# Accessing volley response in another class/method

Tags: android, android-volley

I am beginning in my journey in Android development so might be doing this all wrong. I am trying to get a set of data using Volley and display it which is ok.

The next step I need to do is use the data to make further requests. 
The first request gets a list of sports teams.
I then want to make a request for each team to get the players.

Ideally what I'd like to do is make the first request and return the `JSONobject` to be used with another class. I have no idea how i would do this.

```
teamData.getTeams(
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

               //i want to get this out somehow
               JSONObject thing = response;

}//end on response
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //Show error or whatever...
                }
            });
```

I'm happy to expand on this if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volley is enqueuing the request so it fires a request after the older one has returned success or error.
So you can enqueue a new request in the success of the older.

Exemple : in your response of your team request you add a new request as you did `JSONObject thing = response;`

This is an exemple of mine witch imports multiple projects and then imports each project infos:

```
  public void importProjects() {
    Response.Listener<JSONArray> jsonArrayResponseListener;
    String url = Globals.getApiBaseUrl() + GET_PROJECTS_URL;
    jsonArrayResponseListener = new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            try {
                ArrayList<Project> projects = MyJsonParser.getInstance().parseProjects(response);

                if (projects.size() > 0) {
                    for (Project p : projects) {
                        importProject(p); //####### HERE IS THE KEY :: this methode is the same of this one. It calls other volley request.#######//
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("SyncRngine", "THIS IS AN ERROR");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Response.ErrorListener responseError;
    responseError = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    };

    url = formatUrl(url, params);
    Log.i("URL IMPORT PROJECTS", url);
    MyVolleyJsonArrayRequest customRequest = new MyVolleyJsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, jsonArrayResponseListener, responseError);
    MyVolley.getInstance(activity.getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(customRequest);

}
```

And now the défénition of `importProject(Project p)` :

```
 public void importProject(final Project project) {
    String url = Globals.getApiBaseUrl() + GET_PROJECT_URL;

    Response.Listener<JSONArray> jsonArrayResponseListener;
    jsonArrayResponseListener = new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            try {
                useProjectInfos(response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Response.ErrorListener responseError;
    responseError = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    };
    url = url + "/" + project.getProjectID();
    url = formatUrl(url, params);
    MyVolleyJsonArrayRequest customRequest = new MyVolleyJsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, jsonArrayResponseListener, responseError);
    MyVolley.getInstance(activity.getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(customRequest);

}
```

Comment: Excellent, that worked. I tried something similar before but didn't seem to work. Now I have to work out how to display the data. I've got the list of teams displaying but can't get the players to show. Time to do some reading I think.

Comment: you can just create a function in your activity witch do the process and call it in your success or in your error listeners like this : 
` if (activity instanceof MainActivity) {
                            ((MainActivity) activity).updateHeaderUiComponents();
                        }`

and please put it on resolved . good luck :)